# update column value after insert and period of time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table including `status` that default value is `0` when it inserted in the first time, I want to change this value from `0` to `1` after this row inserted in 24 hours, that means status value changed to `1` after `24 hours` from inserted.

Using MySQL. How can I do this?

Comment: why not insert the timestamp? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the right approach.  I mean, you could set up an event that gets processed for every row, but that could add a lot of load to your database.

Instead, if `status` is merely saying that the row is less or more than one day old, put a creation date into the table and use a view:

```
create view v_table as
     select t.*, (creation_date >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) as status
     from table t;
```

If `status` can be changed by other means, then call it something like `_status` and do:

```
create view v_table as
     select t.*,
            (case when creation_date >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day then 1 else _status end) as status
     from table t;
```